# Append string and format Array Values

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a array with values and want to append a link to all the values of array assign back the value to same array.

```
string [] files = null; // will contain array of string values

string[] attachmentFilePath = files;
string[] attachmentFileName = files;
```

I want to append "http://www.google.com" with every value in the files array and  assign it to attachmentFilePath.

I have tried a lot using `string.format("google.com",files[index])`

```
for(var i = 0; i<files.count();i++)
{
    files[index] = string.format("http://www.google.com",files[index]);
}
```

tried a lot but some or the other way the code gives error or index out of bounds or null reference exception.

I need the string to appended like 'http://www.google.com/files.value'

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: How do you want to append it? just at the end of each string? with a space? please show format. In addition please show what you have tried..

Comment: I have tried a lot using 

string.format("http://www.google.com",files[index])

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to the question. having `index` I guess it includes also a loop

Comment: In addition what is the desired format?

Comment: Please give us example content and desired output (at least a few lines/itterations). Right now your question is less then clear.

Comment: @Christopher i have updated the questions. i need the array value to be like : www.google.com/{fileValue}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `string.Format` requires the string to be in the proper format for formatting:

```
string.Format("some string with place holder: {0}","some string to put");
```

If your string does not have the placeholders (as in your case) it doesn't do anything. Read more about [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Solutions:**

1. Simple `for` loop:

   ```
   var yourString = "http://www.google.com/";
   var attachmentFilePath = new string[files.Length];
   for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
   {
       attachmentFilePath[i] = yourString + files[i];
   }
   ```
2. Linq:

   ```
   var yourString = "http://www.google.com/";
   var attachmentFilePath = files.Select(s => yourString + s).ToArray();
   ```

*And of course you can correctly use `string.Format` to any of these two solutions where appending the strings. Just see it is has the place holder in the place you want*

Comment: minor but I think you meant `s => yourString + "/" + s` ? as the OP wants it appended at the end of `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: the concatenation is still the wrong way around I think it should be `yourString + s` instead of `s + yourString` and same for the first example. should be `yourString + files[i]` i believe :)

Comment: @Aominè - haha true. Stupid of me. Long day

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the task at hand with something along the lines of:

```
string[] attachmentFilePath = files.Select(x => $"http://www.google.com/{x}")
                                   .ToArray();
```